# Why would I be getting back only 100 transactions even in production in Plaid

Tags: production, plaid

We got our production access yesterday and I set the environment to `production` and plugged in the new, production secret key. When I get back my access token it's of the form `access-production-XXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX`. When I request transactions though, the "total transactions" field says a big number, like 745 in the example before me, and the number of transactions actually returned in the transactions array remains limited to 100.

Why? Why am I not seeing the whole 745?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/transactions/get` takes a `count` parameter that indicates how many transactions to request. By default, this is 100. To get more than 100 transactions, you need to modify the parameter, and to get more than 500 transactions, you need to make multiple requests.

More info:

https://plaid.com/docs/api/products/#transactions-get-request-options-count
https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/pagination/